# Can we dynamically configure the 'KeepAliveSecs ' parameter based on the load in WebLogic?

Tags: weblogic, keep-alive, appserver

I am new to WebLogic administration.

I wanted to understand how 'KeepAliveSecs' is related to the maximum number of clients on the server. Is it better to use a static 'KeepAliveSecs' value or can we use a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeepAliveSecs is the time a tcp socket connection is kept open for any incoming requests, it helps in improving I/O performance. Setting it to a constant value is recommended, this value is not dynamic as its to do with the core tcp layer and that is not dynamic yet.